# Read CSV file into python dictionary with duplicate entries

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file which looks likes

[image: CSV File Image]

and below code reads CSV file and store data in the dictionary

```py
from pprint import pprint

d = {}
with open("Book1.csv") as f:
    headers = [header.strip() for header in next(f).split(",")[1:]]
    for line in f:
        values = [value.strip() for value in line.split(",")]
        d[values[0]] = dict(zip(headers, values[1:]))
    pprint(d)
```

Above code gives output as follows:

```py
{
  '01-01-2020': {'name': 'z', 'time': '00:00:00', 'value': '23.2'},
  '02-01-2020': {'name': 'b', 'time': '00:05:00', 'value': '23.2'}
}
```

But the problem is that duplicate data is not stored in dictionary it only stores last record from csv file.
I want all the record from csv file to dictionary.

Comment: the `date` column is your key, how are you planning on retrieving a record of data if the key is not unique? I suggest you look at other data structures. maybe read each line into an object and store it in a list.

Comment: Key should be identical and that's why the duplicate value is not stored in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can put list in your `d` dictionaries instead of one single element.

```py
from pprint import pprint

with open("Book1.csv") as f:
    headers = [header.strip() for header in next(f).split(",")[1:]]
    d = {}
    for line in f:
        values = [value.strip() for value in line.split(",")]
        d.setdefault(values[0], [])
        d[values[0]].append(dict(zip(headers, values[1:])))
pprint(d)
```